# how do i use a variable in my sql statement

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class insert {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        
        String url =  "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/datenbank";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "123456";
        
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        
        try {
            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            
            String sql = "INSERT INTO bestenliste "
                    + "(SpielerName)"
                    + Login.nameWeiss;   //this is the varialbe i want to insert into the column SpielerName

            stmt.execute(sql);
            
            System.out.println("Insert Complete");
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Login.nameWeiss)' at line 1

Comment: Have you read the mysql documentation to see what a *valid* SQL INSERT looks like?  Also you should be using proper bind parameters.

Comment: [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

The ‘values ()’ are missing. Try:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO bestenliste "
                + "(SpielerName)"
                + “ values (‘“ + Login.nameWeiss + “‘)”;
```

Also, the query should be parameterised. The version above is inefficient and vulnerable to sql injection. Try:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO bestenliste "
                + "(SpielerName)"
                + “values (?)”;

PreparedStatement createPlayer = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

createPlayer.setString(1, Login.nameWeiss);
createPlayer.executeUpdate();
```